# How to write an exponential learning rate decay algorithm while using JAX's version of Adam Optimizer

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning, neural-network, jax

I am writing a Physics Informed Neural Network (PINN) code and have been using the JAX library for the same. I have been using the 'Adam' optimizer from JAX's 'example_libraries.optimizers' Module. I want to train it in such a way that the learning rate (step size) starts at something, let's say 1e-2 and then exponentially decreases throughtout the iterations and ends at a certain value, let's say 1e-4 at the final iteration.

I haave been using the sample code as provided by the JAX documentation. The block of code dealing with the optimization is given below:

```
step_size=1e-3
train_iters=100000
@jit
def resnet_update(params, opt_state):
    value, grads = value_and_grad(objective)(params)
    opt_state = opt_update(0, grads, opt_state)
    return get_params(opt_state), opt_state, value

opt_init, opt_update, get_params = adam(step_size, b1=0.9, b2=0.999, eps=1e-8)
opt_state = opt_init(params)

for i in range(train_iters):
  params, opt_state, value = resnet_update(params, opt_state)
  if i % 1000 == 0:
         print("Iteration {0:3d} objective {1}".format(i,
                                                      (objective)(params)))
```

How do I modify it to achive the thing I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`optax`](https://github.com/deepmind/optax/tree/master) the most popular lib for optimizers in Jax:

```py
learning_rate = optax.exponential_decay(
    init_value,
    transition_steps,
    decay_rate,
    transition_begin,
    staircase,
    end_value,
)
adam = optax.adam(learning_rate=lr, ...)
```

The documentation [here](https://optax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#optax.exponential_decay).